# Can Clash of Clans be linked with facebook account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have linked the game to my google+ account but for Facebook it always says **"disconnected"**.

Can Clash of Clans only be linked to Google+ ?

I have also tried to connect to Facebook while I was not connected to Google+, but it was still showing as disconnected. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You should be able to connect with FB. I don't use my FB account, but I know someone who does and he has no issues whatsoever AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, it should work, I connected with Facebook

Comment: Not to sound like a jerk, but have you tried pressing the button that says "disconnected"?

Answer (score 3):

When your Clash of Clans say your Facebook is disconnected, it's usually because your authentication/access token (the one given to Supercell and your client when you were prompted for authentication) has expired. It expires when one of the following happens:

- Your Facebook password was changed.
- You manually chose to deauthorize the app (in your [Apps page](https://www.facebook.com/games/manage)), simply click the cog wheel and refer to the pop-up box.
- Expires after some time.

You can read up more about Authentication tokens [on the Facebook Developers' page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

---

As for linking with Facebook - It is not possible, as Facebook does not allow for apps to store identification data (not access tokens, client IDs or changable account identifiers), but actual static identifiers (like a [SteamID](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID)).

So, there is no way to restore without using Games Center (for iOS) or logging with a Google Play (Android) account, as these services do allow the game (or for *Clash of Clans*' case; their servers) to store a static identifier ID.

---

Lastly, as for the game saying you're constantly getting disconnected, are you:

1. Constantly changing your password/deauthorizing apps?
2. Not using the Facebook app or Safari (for iOS), or using the in-built browser(for Android) to do the authentication?

If so, you may want to consider using Safari (for iOS), or for Android devices, a modern browser such as [Google Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) or [Mozilla Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en).

Alternatively, it's the safest to use the Facebook app for both device types as Facebook stores the data on the app too, along with logging-in not being a hassle (in case of cross-browser/app errors).

Answer (score -2):

**Step 1** : In Your device Download **Puffin Browser**(free)<----you can Google it or via store

**Step 2** : After Download,Install It and Open Browser and go to Facebook

**Step 3** : Open Your Facebook account(maybe it will ask for your mobile number or email conformation)

**Step 4** : After successfully Logging close your browser and go to clash of clash and connect FB with your id pass

Once CoC connected with FB You can uninstall browser.

Comment: Why do you even need Puffin Browser?  What does it do that the regular browser doesn't?

Comment: puffin browser open facebook as a desktop mode 
and fb unable to verify coc server