# Recovering my Clash of clans and save to other device

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to recover my clash of clans that connected to facebook. And i will save it to google play store. But I dont know how.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192516/can-clash-of-clans-be-linked-with-facebook-account?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Clash of clans is not connected to your facebook. Your data is only covered by Game Center (iOS) or Google Play Store/Games (Android). You can always contact Supercell through Help and Support in the settings (cog icon above Shop button). Provided by your problem/issue, your in-game name, etc. describing your account. Don't worry, Supercell will asked more questions regarding your account for recovery.